# Rebinding javascript after ajax renders new partial in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question and answer site. When a person correctly answers a question and click a button a new question is provided. I am using "remote: true" to do this via ajax in rails 3. The problem is that when the new question partial is inserted, the javascript doesn't work. There are a couple of buttons that use javascript to show clues but that is broken. I assume the problem is that the buttons are not bound when the partial is inserted.

the `update.js.erb` looks like this:

```
$("#question").replaceWith( ' <%= j render "enrollments/question" %> ');
```

What do I need to do to get the buttons working again?

**Update**

I can solve this problem by simply adding the javascript code that is loaded originally again after the partial is rendered. Is this the only way to do this or is there a better way to set the event listeners agin?

Comment: Can you share _question.html.erb?

Comment: It's a bit long. The problem is clearly just that the javascript that is loaded originally is not binding to the ids of the partial. If I just add the code again it works but that doesn't seem very dry.